# Cannot run OpenCL on an NVIDIA Card ( 'CL/cl_platform.h': No such file or directory)

Tags: opencl

I am trying to run code written in OpenCL on an NVIDIA GPU.

- I installed NVIDIA GPU Computing Tool Kit
- I added the include and lib path to my project properties
- I set the environment variable by the path of bin

But I get this error:

```
CL/cl_platform.h': No such file or directory
```

I notice my project confused between these paths:

1. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.1\include
   (which has Cl/cl_platform.h   but project do not see it  although   I
   set it in include properties )
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\CL

I need the first path but it only sees the second path. What should I do ?

Comment: I take it you are using Visual Studio?

Comment: yes Visual studio 2010

Comment: What do you mean that the project is 'confused' between the paths? Where in your project properties have you input the first path, and where are you seeing the second path shown?

Comment: I set  the first path in Project properties 
I mean---> Right click on project name  --> properties -->Additional include Directories --> " put the first path there" 
********************************************
== 
Second path contents  appear when I write #include  as Auto complete

Comment: + 
Also I discover my project opencl.lib !!!!!!