# OpenCL code on Nvidia GEFORCE using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I am new to OpenCL, I have been trying to test run OpenCL code on Nvidia. I have installed the CUDA 6.0 tool kit and I have added the .cu and .cl extensions in visual studio 2010. I have included OpenCL.lib in the Linker tab of project properties. I have included  the needed libraries in visual studio 2010. But, when I compile my code I get an error "nvcc : fatal error : Don't know what to do with matvec.cl". Can somebody shed some light on this issue. I have been at it for the past two days. There were  previous questions related to this, but there is no reply for one question, here is the link: 
[Cannot run OpenCL on an NVIDIA Card ( 'CL/cl_platform.h': No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793748/cannot-run-opencl-on-an-nvidia-card-cl-cl-platform-h-no-such-file-or-direct)
and another the link in the reply does not work for some reason, here is the link:
[How to configure OpenCL in visual studio2010 for nvidia's gpu on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918320/how-to-configure-opencl-in-visual-studio2010-for-nvidias-gpu-on-windows)
If someone can also provide a link for this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have configured Visual Studio to compile `.cl` files with `nvcc`. This is what you should do for CUDA files (`.cu`), but OpenCL kernel source code is compiled at runtime, and should not be compiled by anything at application build time. Just remove this configuration option, and you should be good to go.

One thing you *might* want to do with `.cl` files is have them automatically copied to the application binary directory, so that the application can find them easily when it wants to load them. This is just a matter of preference.

Comment: thanks for your reply. After reading your answer, I selected the properties option for my matvec.cl file and selected the option for itemtype "Does not participate in build", would that be correct. I am sorry but can you please elaborate on how I can remove this configuration option for my "matvec.cl" file.

Comment: @Steve Yes, that option sounds correct - as long as Visual Studio isn't trying to compile the file, you should be fine.

Comment: thank  you for your prompt answer. Just one more question, I am trying to compile a matrix vector multiplication program. If I run the program it says "matrix vector multiplication unsuccessful". Could you please mention the exact libraries that need to be included in Visual Studio for processing OpenCL code.

Comment: @Steve If the program runs at all, then you have the correct library configuration. That error message is far too vague to be able to diagnose the problem - there are tons of potential reasons for any given OpenCL failing. You need to try and find out where that error is originating from (e.g. which OpenCL function call is failing). If you post some code or a link to an example you are trying (maybe in a new question?), we might be able to help.

Comment: thank you. I will try again and see if the issue can be resolved else I will post a new question with the code along with the issue. Thanks again for your help, Jprice.